# Nasm - Change variable in different threads

Tags: multithreading, winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

I have a program that has a main thread and a second thread. The second thread modifies a global variable which then will be used in the main thread. But somehow the changes I make in the second thread are not shown in the main thread.

```
section .bss USE32
  global var
  var resd 1

section .text USE32
  ..start:
  push 0
  push 0
  push 0
  push .second
  push 0
  push 0
  call [CreateThread]
  mov eax, 1
  cmp [var], eax ; --> the content of var and '1' are not the same. Which is confusing since I set the content of var to '1' in the second thread
  ;the other code here is not important

.second:
  mov eax, 1
  mov [var], eax
  ret
```

(This is a simplification of my real program which creates threads in a loop; [I haven't tested this exact code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844018/nasm-change-variable-in-different-threads/66844358?noredirect=1#comment118158588_66844358).)

Comment: why content of the var must be '1' **at this point** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't `join` the new thread (wait for it to exit); there's no reason to assume that it's finished (or even fully started) when CreateThread returns to the main thread.

You could spin-wait until you see a non-zero value in `[var]`, and count how many iterations that takes, if you want to benchmark thread-startup overhead + inter-core latency.

```
   ...
   call  [CreateThread]
   mov   edi, 1
   cmp   [var], edi
   je   .zero_latency    ; if var already changed

   rdtsc                 ; could put an lfence before and/or after this to serialize execution
   mov  ecx, eax         ; save low half of EDX:EAX cycle count; should be short enough that the interval fits in 32 bits
   xor  esi, esi
  .spin:
   inc  esi            ; ++spin_count
   pause               ; optional, but avoids memory-order mis-speculation when var changes
   cmp  [var], edi
   jne .spin

   rdtsc
   sub  eax, ecx        ; reference cycles since CreateThread returned
   ...
 .zero_latency:         ; jump here if the value already changed before the first iteration
```

Note that `rdtsc` measures in *reference* cycles, not core clock cycles, so turbo matters.  Only doing the low 32 bits of the 64-bit subtraction is fine if the interval is less than 2^32 (e.g. about 1 second on a CPU with a reference frequency of 4.2 GHz, vastly longer than we'd expect here).

`esi` is the spin count.  With `pause` in the loop, you'll do about one check per 100 cycles on Skylake and later, or about one check per 5 cycles on earlier Intel.  Otherwise about one check per core clock cycle.

Comment: I added a loop to the main thread. But the second thread is still not able to modify the global variable `var` so that the new value is visible to the main thread. Is there some keyword I have to use to tell the compiler that this variable can be modified by multiple threads? For example `volatile` in C.

Comment: Volatile in C just means the load or store has to actually happen in asm.  When hand-writing in assembly language, you're already forcing that to happen.  Cache is coherent so stores in one thread definitely become visible to loads in other threads within a few hundreds of nanoseconds.  No special instruction is needed.  That's [*why* `volatile` works in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118).

Comment: @MenNotAtWork: If your spin-loop in main isn't exiting, then you have a bug in your program, e.g. perhaps CreateThread is returning an error without actually creating another thread.  Try putting some other code in the other thread, like a call to `puts`, or a `CreateFile` that will have some visible effect.  Or just set a breakpoint in `.second` and see if it's ever reached.

Comment: @MenNotAtWork:   Note that `push second` is not the same label as `.second`, the `.` is important.  If you have some other `second:` label somewhere, that's what you're passing to CreateThread.  I assumed it was just a typo in the question, but if that's your real code then that's a problem.

Comment: The call to CreateProcess is in a loop in my real program. I simplified the code for the question. I guess by calling multiple threads in my original program I'm overwriting the content of `var` again right after it got changed in the second thread.